# Reading KML Files Using Fastkml

Tags: python, kml

I've searched around quite a bit for this specific Python module, and haven't been able to find a source which points me in the right direction.

I'm trying to read a KML file and display all of the features inside of a folder, I believe I'm achieving this using fastkml, but I have a problem.

Using the following code everything works until the line, len(k.features). I tried printing it, adding quotes as shown in the documentation, but nothing works. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Example: https://github.com/cleder/fastkml

Code:

```
from fastkml import  kml
doc = file("Allpoints.kml").read()
k = kml.KML()
k.from_string(doc)
len(k.features())
```

Answer (score 7):

`features()` returns a generator object that you can iterate over but it doesn't have a `len` function:

```
for f in k.features():
    print(f.name)
```

if you really need the length then you can use a list comprehension to turn the generator into a list:

```
features = list(k.features())
len(features)
```

Comment: `list(k.features())` sound also turn it into a list.

Answer (score 0):

O(1) solution...

```
from fastkml import  kml
doc = file("Allpoints.kml").read()
k = kml.KML()
k.from_string(doc)
len(k._features)
```